# Do I have the right start for this proof?

Tags: proof-writing

I'm trying to prove the following,

> Suppose R is a partial order on $A$, $B\subseteq A$, and $b\in B$.
>
> Prove that if $b$ is the smallest element of $B$, then it is also the
>   greatest lower bound of $B$.

My givens and goals so far are:

Givens

$b$ is the smallest element of $B$

Goals
$$
(x\in A) \land (\forall y \in B (xRy) \land (\forall z \in A (\forall w \in B (zRw))\rightarrow xRz)
$$
I don't know how to proceed from here. Could someone help me with this?

Thanks.

Comment: First, write out what it means for $x$ to be the smallest element of $B$.

Comment: I assume you mean b not x. That would be $\forall$ x $\in$ B(bRx)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take $L(B)$ as the set of the Lower bounds of $B$, defined by:
$$L(B)=\left\{x\in A\Big/\forall y\in B \ \ \ xRy\right\}$$

- **Givens** $b$ is the smallest element of $b$ is equivalent to :
  $$\begin{align}b&\in B&\text{ and } &&\forall x\in B\ \ \ bRx \end{align}$$
- **Goal** $b$ is the greatest element of lower bounds of $B$:
  $$\begin{align}b&\in L(B) &\text{ and }&& \forall t\in L(B)\ \ \ tRb \end{align}$$

Because $b$ is the smallest element of $B$ then $\forall x\in B\ \ \  bRx$ then $$b\in L(B)\tag1$$

Now given an element of $t\in L(B)$ we have $tRx$ for all $x\in B$ in particular $tRb$ because $b\in B$, so :
$$\forall t\in L(B)\, \ \  tRb \tag2$$

$(1)$ and $(2)$ means exactly that $b$ is the greatest element of $L(B)$

Comment: Hi could you tell me how you separated givens and goals?

Comment: I think that if you formalize the problem this way then you can see it very simply and you will not be lost between Quantifiers !

Answer (score 0):

Since $b$ is the smallest element of $B$, we have that

1. $b \in B$ and
2. for every $x \in B$, $b \leq x$.

Hence $b$ is a lower bound for $B$. If $b'$ is another lower bound, then $b' \leq b$ (since $b \in B$). Hence $b = \sup B$.

Comment: How can you conclude that b' <= b? Where did you get the <= sign?

Comment: Definition of lower bound!